# Does the Ubuntu website use customary or SI definitions?

Tags: 16.04, ubuntu-website

On the "Recommended System Requirements" [page for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop), it gives the recommended system requirements—it gives one of these as "2 GB system memory".

Ubuntu *the OS* has switched to SI definitions for the prefixes used, so 1 GB = 10<sup>9</sup> bytes, not 2<sup>30</sup> bytes. However, most measurements of RAM use customary definitions, so 1 GB = 2<sup>30</sup> bytes.

Therefore, when I see the recommended memory on the Ubuntu website being stated as "2 GB", should I assume they're saying 2×10<sup>9</sup> B or 2×2<sup>30</sup> B?

Comment: Would that really matter at all? It's only a difference of roughly 145MB or 7% - also it's only a *recommendation* anyway, not a fixed minimal requirement.

Comment: If it didn't matter to me, would I have asked?

Comment: If having 145 MB more or less is an issue for you you probably don't have enough memory to run Ubuntu in a satisfying manner. Try one of the more light-weighted flavours of Ubuntu (Xubuntu or Lubuntu) or even a different Linux distribution.

Comment: This is **on topic**. It's about Ubuntu. We do not only serve as a help desk (thankfully).

Comment: @Tim: **Thank** you. I wish people would just answer my question, instead of trying to suggest reasons why it's not needed.

Answer (score 2):

RAM is always declared in octal values. There is no RAM that is manufactured to a specification of 1000 bytes == 1 KB. RAM is always marketed as GB, and is always 1024 bytes == 1 KB.

The use of GiB versus GB is primarily for storage, where Hard Drive and other storage device manufacturers have generally always used 1000 bytes == 1 KB, and to make the difference clear in the user interface.

If you believe for some reason that the web site is inaccurate, there is a link at the bottom of every page for *Report a bug on this site*, where you can report the issue.

Comment: Well, the storage manufacturers did that so their numbers can appear bigger than they are. They can do that because disks do not have to come in capacities of powers of 2.

Comment: Well my HDD is manufactured to be 2,000,398,934,016 bytes, which is neither 2 x 10^12 or 2^40 (2199023255552) so I'm not sure what your point is - how do we know which Ubuntu is using?

Comment: The point isn't to answer every specific case. It's a general answer to the question, which is about RAM, not storage. Decimal is used for storage, and octal is always used for RAM. ∎

Comment: My point is that Ubuntu the *OS* uses prefixes accurately and precisely: when it means binary values, it uses binary prefixes; likewise, when it means decimal values, it uses decimal prefixes. So it doesn't matter if RAM is always octal or not; if Ubuntu wants to be consistent, one needs to know whether they're using the right prefixes on the website as well.

Comment: @SarahofGaia: That's a good point but you should bring that up with Canonical, the firm that runs http://ubuntu.com/. We can't do anything about it here.

Comment: @DavidFoerster: Well I wasn't sure if it was already decided or not. If they already *were* being consistent, then I wouldn't need to bring it up with them. I'd only need to bring it up with them if they were not being consistent. Hence why I was asking.